# OnDraw is not drawing anything into MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-canvas, osmdroid

I am trying to draw a solid green rectangle into a canvas and then add that canvas to MapView.  However, after adding the "canvas" to MapView nothing appears into it.  I has been looking around but I cannot figure out is wrong.  I am using OSMDroid for the MapView.

Here is the code for the class:

public class DrawFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

```
      MapView mapView;
GeoPoint geoPoint
Canvas  canvas = new Canvas();
private FrameLayout layout; 

public DrawFrameLayout(Context context, MapView mapView, GeoPoint geoPoint{
    super(context);

    layout = new FrameLayout(context);
    layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    this.mapView = mapView;
    this.geoPoint= geoPoint
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    onDraw(canvas);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

    addView(layout, params); 
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // draw a solid green rectangle
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 5, 200, 30, paint);
}
}
```

Here is how I instantiate the class from the main activity:

```
            DrawFrameLayout frameLayout = new DrawFrameLayout(mapView.getContext(), mapView, geoPoint);

        MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, geoPoint,
        MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0, 0);
        mapView.addView(frameLayout, params);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Overlay and add it to overlays list of the MapView. Sample:

```
FingerLineOverlay fingerLineOverlay = new FingerLineOverlay();
mapView.getOverlays().add(fingerLineOverlay);

public class FingerLineOverlay extends Overlay{
    private final Paint mPaint;

    public FingerLineOverlay() {
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {
        c.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 500, mPaint);
    }
}
```

More info: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Making-Custom-Overlays